# warning: Could not find remote branch to clone when pod install

Tags: git, github, cocoapods, git-clone

Try to pod install.
pod run successfully at first and then i change it to older version. And run well
When i return it to new version it show error

> [!] Error installing MoEngage-iOS-SDK [!] /usr/bin/git clone
> https://github.com/moengage/MoEngage-iOS-SDK.git
> /var/folders/nb/z9nbbmp54850cf8bpzg780k4ngx6nd/T/d20220421-1588-otwiqf
> --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch moengage-8.1.0
>
> Cloning into
> '/var/folders/nb/z9nbbmp54850cf8bpzg780k4ngx6nd/T/d20220421-1588-otwiqf'...
> warning: Could not find remote branch moengage-8.1.0 to clone. fatal:
> Remote branch moengage-8.1.0 not found in upstream origin

If i try to git clone https://github.com/moengage/MoEngage-iOS-SDK.git manually. This works well. Is there any problem with my folder?

Comment: Looks like there is no branch named `moengage-8.1.0` on the git repo. Thats what is causing it to fail. I could see this branch - https://github.com/moengage/MoEngage-iOS-SDK/tree/8.1.0-release. Check your podspec file and update to correct branch name if specified.

Comment: @SatyaS, but my friends in another mac, can pod install well